# Are there any reports on Hardware errors affecting experiments?

Tags: experiments, hardware

I recently wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781091/562769) as a list of what I have seen / can think of as problem sources that make it hard to reproduce (replicate?) an experiment. I think I have seen most of them, except for hardware errors.

My thought was this: A typical computer vision experiment might run a training on a GPU for many hours / several days. Even if a bit-flip happens only once every $10^9$ FLOPs, that would be 11500 errors per second with an [Nvidia Titan GTX 1080 Ti](http://www.gamestar.de/artikel/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1080-ti-schneller-als-eine-titan-x-fuer-699-us-dollar,3310460.html). I don't know how this error would affect later calculations (how the problem is numerically conditioned).

So: **Are there any reports on Hardware errors affecting experiments?**

(Blog posts, journal articles, posters?)

Answer (score 1):

Memory corruption seems to be an issue that is important enough for companies to buy expensive ECC memory for their clusters.
The [Wikipedia article on ECC memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) lists some causes for memory corruption, including (to my surprise and delight) cosmic rays and ingenious hackers.

Comment: Just because there is a produce, it doesn't mean there is a need. See [Homeopathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeopathy), [Horoscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horoscope) and many more.